If the logarithm of two sequences gets close together, do the sequences get close together?
I should define what I mean by two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ that are close together. What I mean is that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that for $n \geq N$ we have $|a_n-b_n| < \epsilon$. I will write $a_n \to b_n$ in this case. Neither sequence need converge. Now suppose that $\ln(a_n) \to \ln(b_n)$ for sequences that don't break the logarithm. Does $a_n \to b_n$?

$a_n \to b_n$ has no meaning.

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln a_n-\ln b_n=0$ is equivalent to $\left[\forall n,b_n>0\land \lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\frac{a_m}{b_m}=1\right]$.

@geetha290krm The OP defined what he meant by $a_n \to b_n$, so it has a meaning.

OP - what you mean is $a_n - b_n \to 0.$ Because $a_n\to b_n$ has no meaning. So your question is: "Does $a_n - b_n\to 0\implies \ln(a_n) - \ln (b_n) \to 0?$"

@Adam rather ⟸.

@AnneBauval sorry yes of course you are right.

No. Counterexample: $a_n=n$, $b_n=n+1$.

$$\log a_n-\log b_n\to0\iff\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to1\iff\frac{a_n-b_n}{b_n}\to0$$
hence, letting $a_n-b_n=c_n$, your question is equivalent to:

does $\frac{c_n}{b_n}\to0$ imply $c_n\to0$?

This translation makes clear that the answer is NO, and helps to find many counterexamples.
